# how to get missing timestamps between the earliest value of day and latest value of day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, interpolation

The df contains indices with NaNs (intentionally).
It contains many dayly ranges of 5 minute stamps, but sometimes there are holes inside those ranges.

Is there a way to get the missing timestamps between the earliest timestamp (= the earliest the has ever been on a day) and the latest time (= the latest the has ever been on a day)?

I mean for example my timeseries could start at 4:35 and end at 23:30 every day, but sometimes even the beginning or the end could be missing on a day.
(for this the earliest timevalue in a day and the latest timevalue "ever" on this index would be necessary, is there a way to do this with second, so that it stays dynamically?)

```
Time                 Vals
2019-06-17 08:45:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 08:50:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 08:55:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:00:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:05:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:10:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:15:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:20:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:25:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:30:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:35:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:40:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:45:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:50:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:55:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:00:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:05:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:10:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:15:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:20:00   NaN 
Name: Vals, dtype: float64

ix = pd.to_datetime(pd.Index("2019-06-17 08:45:00","2019-06-17 08:50:00","2019-06-17 08:55:00","2019-06-17 09:00:00","2019-06-17 09:05:00","2019-06-17 09:10:00","2019-06-17 09:15:00","2019-06-17 09:20:00","2019-06-17 09:25:00","2019-06-17 09:30:00","2019-06-17 09:35:00","2019-06-17 09:40:00","2019-06-17 09:45:00","2019-06-17 09:50:00","2019-06-17 09:55:00","2019-06-17 10:00:00","2019-06-17 10:05:00","2019-06-17 10:10:00","2019-06-17 10:15:00","2019-06-17 10:20:00")
```

(in the end it needs to be a pandas datetime index again)

EDIT: (to avoid misunderstandings)

the index above actually consists of **millions of days**, some having some holes between the "ranges" they start and end. these timestamp holes **between start and end**  need to be added (while the times ouside of the range should *not* be added).
Is there a way to do this efficiently without doing it for every range manually?

one could get the earliest daytime (e.g. 04:35) and the latest (e.g. 22:45) and then fill these ranges on every day.
**But how to do that in an efficient way with millions of days**?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, pandas date_range might be relevant for this:
Eg. if you want to get the timeseries for one date and the times you mentioned, you
could try:

```
pd.date_range(start="2019-06-17 04:35", end="2019-06-17 23:30", freq="5T")
```

Comment: My text above maybe wasnt clear enough i guess, (because the index actually consists of millions of days) Is there a way to do this efficiently with daytimes? (like: everyday from (8:30 till 18:30)?

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you just use the `.head(1)` and `.tail(1)` functions? So in this example `df[‘Time’].head(1`) and the same for tail.

Comment: I guess not directly, since the index in reality consists of multiple days. So the earliest daytime that occoures in the index has to be figured out by hour minute and second.

Comment: ah I see, not really sure how you could do that sadly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem can be rephrased as follows: if a particular timestamp exists for one day, it should exist for all days. Let me know if I understand the problem correctly.

If this is what you are after, you can

1. get the unique dates and times
2. build a new index from the Cartesian products of these dates and times
3. use `pd.DataFrame.reindex`

Assuming your data is stored in a DataFrame called `df`, you can implement this like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# change index to date-time MultiIndex
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.index.date,df.index.time))

# get unique dates and times
dates = df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
times = df.index.get_level_values(1).unique() # <- time intervals are defined here

# create new index from cartesian product of dates and times
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates,times])
df = df.reindex(idx)

# back to original index format: reduce MultiIndex to 1D datetime index, sort
df.index = [datetime.combine(date,time) for date,time in df.index.values]
df = df.sort_index()
```

**Edit: alternative times as requested in comments**

If the time intervals to follow another rule (e.g. if you want a fixed interval as in the example, or specific start and end values), you can change the definition of `times` accordingly. For example, if you want to have an entry for every five minute interval on each day, replace the line that starts with `times = ...` by the following expression:

```
times = pd.date_range(start="2000-01-01 00:00", end="2000-01-01 23:59", freq="5T").time
```

**Example (baseline version)**

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Vals':range(6)})
df.index =  pd.to_datetime(pd.Index(["2019-06-17 08:45:00",
                                     "2019-06-17 08:50:00",
                                     "2019-06-17 08:55:00",
                                     "2019-06-17 09:00:00",
                                     "2019-06-18 08:40:00",
                                     "2019-06-18 08:55:00"]))
print(df)
                     Vals
2019-06-17 08:45:00     0
2019-06-17 08:50:00     1
2019-06-17 08:55:00     2
2019-06-17 09:00:00     3
2019-06-18 08:40:00     4
2019-06-18 08:55:00     5
```

Output:

```
print(df)
                     Vals
2019-06-17 08:40:00   NaN
2019-06-17 08:45:00   0.0
2019-06-17 08:50:00   1.0
2019-06-17 08:55:00   2.0
2019-06-17 09:00:00   3.0
2019-06-18 08:40:00   4.0
2019-06-18 08:45:00   NaN
2019-06-18 08:50:00   NaN
2019-06-18 08:55:00   5.0
2019-06-18 09:00:00   NaN
```

Comment: could you describe what you exactly mean by "  you can change the definition of times accordingly. " ?  Otherwise the result looks pretty good. I am planning to do this by selecting a specific subselection of a df I want to "clean" and then appending the new won timestamps to the whole index via union() and reindex().

Comment: Also: is there a way to do this from 00:00 to 23:59 (only) for every day date which is included? ( in case the full day needs to be extracted afterwards and cleand with a different method)

Comment: which rules should the index follow between 00:00 and 23:59? E.g. do you want a fixed interval such as 5min? Are the existing inputs guaranteed to be on these intervals?

Comment: fixed intervall, yes.     In the case of 00:00 and 23:59 the existing inputs are NOT guaranteed to be on these intervals. In fact, this practice would be to fill all the ranges which are completely not represented in the dataset.

Comment: @JulietVictor Its like 24/? (instead of 24/7) every 5 minutes but only on the days already contained.

Comment: @Iroquois_Pliskin check the modification I added to my answer

Comment: @Iroquois_Pliskin does it work? If yes, please accept the answer. If not, please provide more information.